# Hide the dynamic li depending on the attribute text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
 <li text="view">view</li>
 <li text="edit">edit</li>
 <li text="save">save</li>
 <li text="Overview">OverView</li>
 <li text="view">Delete</li>
</ul>
```

Contents are dynamic.

I want to hide the li depending on the content . Clicking on menu this submenu will display with these options .

If a particular user i want to hide li .

```
if( user == 'some user' )
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
     $(li).attr(text) == 'edit'  then hide that one.

    })
}
```

It may come new contents also , how can hide ,please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attributes selector

```
if( user == 'some user' )
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
         $('li[text="edit"]').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('li[text="edit"]').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an element by specific attribute, then use [jquery attr selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
For your case, you can use `$('li[text="+TEXT+"]').hide()` where TEXT is your specific text.